# why doesn't this variable live long enough?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I'm trying to extract an optional arg from `getopts`, and getting a borrowed value doesn't live long enough error for the variable `s`.

code:

```
let cfgFilePath = match matches.opt_str("c") {
    Some(s) => Some(Path::new(&s.clone())),
    None => None
};
```

error:

```
main.rs:29:36: 29:45 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
main.rs:29         Some(s) => Some(Path::new(&s.clone())),
                                              ^~~~~~~~~
main.rs:31:7: 65:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 10 at 31:6...
main.rs:31     };
main.rs:32     let tmpdir = Path::new(&matches.opt_str("t").unwrap_or("/tmp/".to_string()));
main.rs:33     let name = matches.opt_str("n").unwrap_or_else(||{
main.rs:34         print_usage(&program, opts);
main.rs:35         panic!("error: -n NAME required");
main.rs:36     });
           ...
```

This happens regardless of `.clone()`, `.to_owned()`, `.to_str()` or anything else I've thought to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Path::new(&x)` returns an `&Path` that borrows it's contents from `x`.

```
Some(s) => Some(Path::new(&s.clone())), // Type is Option<&Path>
// reborrow --------------^
```

What you actually want to do is use a `PathBuf` (the owned equivalent of `Path`). `PathBuf` will take ownership of `s` instead of borrowing it.

```
let cfgFilePath = match matches.opt_str("c") {
    Some(s) => Some(PathBuf::from(s)),
    None => None
};
```

Comment: Oh well chalk that up to my foolish expectations of what Path::new would do for me.